# Android TextView setText with Getter return

Tags: java, android

I just try my first Android app and have encountered a problem where I do not really get ahead. In my app I create an `ArrayList` which will filled with Objects. Each Object has four attributes. Now I´d like to write each attribute for each Object in its own specific `TextView`. But there is my Problem. If the same Code is run in a normal Java Application and I use `System.out.Print("getter method")` I get the Value I would like, but if I use `.setText("getter method")` I get what you can see on the screenshot.

ActivityClass:

```
public class ShowBeaconActivity extends Activity {

protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_showbeacons);
    setUpShowBeacons();
}

public void setUpShowBeacons(){
    //
    //Beacon 1
    //
    TextView beaconOneUUID = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.txtBeaconOneUUIDValue);
    beaconOneUUID.setText(BeaconListe.getBeacon(0,"UUID"));

    TextView beaconOneMajor = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.txtBeaconOneMajorValue);
    beaconOneMajor.setText(BeaconListe.getBeacon(0,"Major"));

    TextView beaconOneMinor = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.txtBeaconOneMinorValue);
    beaconOneMinor.setText(BeaconListe.getBeacon(0,"Minor"));

    TextView beaconOneRSSI = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.txtBeaconOneRSSIValue);
    beaconOneRSSI.setText(BeaconListe.getBeacon(0,"RSSI"));
    //
    //Beacon 2
    //
    TextView beaconTwoUUID = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.txtBeaconTwoUUIDValue);
    beaconTwoUUID.setText(BeaconListe.getBeacon(1,"UUID"));
   ...
}
```

}

BeaconClass:

```
public class Beacon {
private String UUID;
private String Major;
private String Minor;
private int RSSI;

public Beacon(String UUID, String Major,String Minor, int RSSI){
    this.UUID = UUID;
    this.Major = Major;
    this.Minor = Minor;
    this.RSSI = RSSI;
}
//
//Getter
//
public String getUUID(){
    return UUID;
}

public String getMajor(){
    return Major;
}

public String getMinor() {
    return Minor;
}

public int getRSSI() {
    return  RSSI;
}
//
//Setter
//
public void setRSSI(int RSSI){
    this.RSSI = RSSI;
}
```

}

BeaconListeClass

```
public class BeaconListe {
private static ArrayList<Beacon>Liste = new ArrayList<Beacon>();
//
//Getter
//
public static String getBeacon(int index, String value){
    String result = "";
    switch(value){
        case "UUID":    result = Liste.get(index).getUUID();
            break;
        case "Major":   result = Liste.get(index).getMajor();
            break;
        case "Minor":   result = Liste.get(index).getMinor();
            break;
        case "RSSI":    int resultTemp = Liste.get(index).getRSSI();
            result = String.valueOf(resultTemp);
            break;
    }
    return result;
}
//
//Setter
//
public static void addBeacon(String UUID, String Major, String Minor, int RSSI){
    Liste.add(new Beacon(UUID, Major, Minor, RSSI));
}
```

}
[App Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tKMJ0.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It can crash because of null value;

```
public static String getBeacon(int index, String value)
    {
        String result = "";
        switch(value){
            Beacon becon = Liste.get(index);
            case "UUID":    
                result = becon!=null?becon.getUUID():"";
                break;
            case "Major":   
                result = becon!=null?becon.getMajor():"";
                break;
            case "Minor":   
                result = becon!=null?becon.getMinor():"";
                break;
            case "RSSI": 
                resultTemp = becon!=null?becon.getRSSI():0;
                result = String.valueOf(resultTemp);
                break;
        }
        return result==null?"":result;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
 TextView beaconOneUUID = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.txtBeaconOneUUIDValue);
if(BeaconListe.getBeacon(0,"UUID") != null){
beaconOneUUID.setText(BeaconListe.getBeacon(0,"UUID"));
}

    TextView beaconOneMajor = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.txtBeaconOneMajorValue);
if(BeaconListe.getBeacon(0,"Major") != null){
 beaconOneMajor.setText(BeaconListe.getBeacon(0,"Major"));
}

    TextView beaconOneMinor = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.txtBeaconOneMinorValue);
if(BeaconListe.getBeacon(0,"Minor") != null){
 beaconOneMinor.setText(BeaconListe.getBeacon(0,"Minor"));
}
    TextView beaconOneRSSI = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.txtBeaconOneRSSIValue);
if(BeaconListe.getBeacon(0,"RSSI") != null){
beaconOneRSSI.setText(BeaconListe.getBeacon(0,"RSSI"));
}
    //
    //Beacon 2
    //
    TextView beaconTwoUUID = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.txtBeaconTwoUUIDValue);
if(BeaconListe.getBeacon(1,"UUID")){
beaconTwoUUID.setText(BeaconListe.getBeacon(1,"UUID"));
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer but it doesn't help. And I do not know why it should have helped. Perhaps i should have mentioned that. If i click on my button "Show Beacons", which opens this activity and If I do not have added at least 4 beacons (it is also the limit) to my list. So if this window pops up i'm pretty sure there is a value in my list for every TextView :)

Answer (score 0):

From what I see, the `.setText("getter methods")` work just fine. The problem is the text that it sets. Check your function in which you populate the `BeaconListe`, which you have not shown here.
I tried your code but with the following

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_showbeacons);
    populateBeaconListe();
    setUpShowBeacons();
}
public void populateBeaconListe(){
    BeaconListe.addBeacon("B1UUID","B1MAJOR","B1MINOR",1111);
    BeaconListe.addBeacon("B2UUID","B2MAJOR","B2MINOR",2222);
    BeaconListe.addBeacon("B3UUID","B3MAJOR","B3MINOR",3333);
    BeaconListe.addBeacon("B4UUID","B4MAJOR","B4MINOR",4444);
}
```

and it works just fine. See screenshot [image: screenshots]

Comment: Thank you for pointing me to the right direction :). I didnt even thought off my addbeacon method could be wrong. All i chanced was "String uuid = String.valueOf((TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtUUID))" to String "uuid = ((TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtUUID)).getText().toString()" and now it works just fine.